# Optimizing Student Test Performance

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, inference, optimization

I am a Secondary Math teacher who is interested in creating effective learning in groups. My desire is to create a system/program that maximizes student Test performance, but I am not exactly sure where to start.

**My idea thus far:**

I have $n$ students, each of which has probability $p_i$ of passing their next Test. The probability is objectively and subjectively determined by the following metrics (subject to change):

- Homework average, $h$, $(0\leq h \leq 100)$
- Number of absences, $a$, $(0\leq a \leq 90)$, and $k$ is the number of class days thus far.
- Prior yearly average in math class, $m$, $(0\leq m \leq 100)$
- Current yearly Test average, $c$, $(0\leq c \leq 100)$
- Efficacy score (subjective, explained below), $e$, $(0\leq e \leq 100)$

Each metric would have its own weight (10%, 15%, 10%, 30%, and 35%, respectively) contributing to students' overall probability.

$$p_i=0.1\left(\frac{h}{100}\right) + 0.15\left(1-\frac{a}{k}\right) + 0.1\left(\frac{m}{100}\right) + 0.3\left(\frac{c}{100}\right) + 0.35\left(\frac{e}{100}\right)$$

Initially, groups of size 2, 3, or 4 students would be selected at random. At the end of every few class meetings, I would give a subjective "efficacy score" to each student based on how well they worked in their assigned group (based on communication, quality/quantity of work completed, etc.)

**What I think I'm looking for:**

A system that attempts to maximize the average probability of a student passing the next assessment. It should make predictions on who will work well together based on updated input from the above metrics.

I have beginner-level coding experience (Python and Java) and a whole month off this summer to work on this. I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction on how to make a system like this come to fruition, or if you have any ideas or constructive comments, those would be appreciated too.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Logan.  This is a noble cause and I'm sure many, if not all, your readers will appreciate the motivation.  However, it's not a good question for this site insofar as it is too broad and general for us to handle.  Could you possibly find a way to narrow it to a definite, clear statistical question that conceivably could be answered in a page or two?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the reply. I have edited my post for clarity. I don't know exactly how to phrase it as a concise statistical question yet. It's too broad of an idea so far, as you have noticed. I am more-so looking to be pointed in the right direction rather than to have a full solution provided. The "machine learning" feel I get from my request is what has me lost. I have no experience with machine-learning, and I feel that may be the crux to the development of my question.